# In opencv4nodejs how to set alpha when calling drawRectangle

Tags: python, node.js, opencv

I want a PNG that is transparent except for a drawn on square. I can achieve this with Python, but I want to do it with Node.

How do I turn this Python code into Node code using opencv4nodejs?

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

blank = np.zeros((400, 500, 4))
cv2.rectangle(blank, (10, 10), (50, 50), (0,255,0,255) )
cv2.imwrite("blankpy.png", blank)
```

blankpy.png (transparent and drawn square):
[image]

Here is my attempt, but the output isn't quite the same

```
const cv = require('./lib/opencv4nodejs');

const blank = new cv.Mat(400, 500, cv.CV_8UC4);
blank.drawRectangle(new cv.Rect(10, 10, 50, 50), new cv.Vec4(0, 255, 0, 255), 2, cv.LINE_8);
cv.imwrite('blankjs.png', blank);
```

blankjs.png (transparent, but no square):
[image]
If I alter it slightly like this, the output is not transparent, but the square is there.

```
const cv = require('./lib/opencv4nodejs');

const emptyMat = new cv.Mat(400, 500, cv.CV_8UC3);
emptyMat.drawRectangle(new cv.Rect(10, 10, 50, 50), new cv.Vec3(0, 255, 0), 2, cv.LINE_8);
cv.imwrite('blankjs.png', emptyMat);
```

blankjs.png (green square but background is not transparent):
[image]

Answer (score 0):

My workaround:

```
const cv = require('./lib/opencv4nodejs');

const emptyMat = new cv.Mat(400, 500, cv.CV_8UC4, [0,0,0,255]);
emptyMat.drawRectangle(new cv.Rect(10, 10, 50, 50), new cv.Vec3(255, 0, 255), 2);
const invertedEmptyMat = emptyMat.bitwiseNot();

cv.imwrite('blankjs.png', invertedEmptyMat);
```